# What does it mean that a matrix is a rank-one modification of an another matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ and the relation between them is that the matrix $A$ is a rank-one modification of a matrix $B^{-1}$? What does this mean?

Comment: I've not heard of this terminology before but my guess would be $A = B^{-1} + C$ where $C$ is a rank one marix. If you add a reference to the work in which you found the term it may be easier to say exactly.

Comment: You are right. I think that what my teacher meant. because a rank one modified matrix can written as $B= A+uv^{T}$. Thank you so much